# PythonでTCP通信のエラー: [WinError 10061] 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。

Tags: python, network, tcp

以下のPythonコードでTCP/IP通信を行おうとしているのですが、特定のソフトウェアとの通信がうまくいきません。

**noLoopBack.py**

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(('192.168.1.5', 49985))
    s.sendall(b'testSend')
```

エラー内容は以下のようなものです。

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。
```

しかし、殆ど同じコードでループバックアドレス(127.0.0.1)に対して送信すると特定のソフトウェアとも通信がうまくいきます。

**loopBack.py**

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 49985))
    s.sendall(b'testSend')
```

ファイアウォールの設定は[ネットの記事](https://faq.nec-lavie.jp/qasearch/1007/app/servlet/qadoc?QID=011761)等を参考にして一時的に無効にしてみたのですが、変化がありませんでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
また、Python単体で作成したTCP/IPサーバーのコードでは192.168.1.5と127.0.0.1共に受信が出来ております。
私の使用している特定のソフトウェアのみで受信ができないという問題が起きるようです。

受信に使用したTCP/IPサーバーのコード

**tcpServer.py**

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('', 49985))
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

このような場合、ファイアウォールによって通信がブロックされている以外に何か考えられる原因がありますでしょうか？
もし、ファイアウォールによってブロックされている場合、どのような方法でブロックを解除できますでしょうか？

追記：netstat -an の結果は以下のようになっていました。

```
アクティブな接続

  プロトコル  ローカル アドレス      外部アドレス           状態
  TCP         0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:1714           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:1715           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:1947           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:7680           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:49665          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:49666          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:49667          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:49675          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:49694          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         0.0.0.0:63939          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:5354         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:5354         127.0.0.1:49771        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:5354         127.0.0.1:49772        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:5939         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:6463         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:7500         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:7501         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:15292        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:15393        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:16494        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:27015        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:30000        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:45623        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:49309        127.0.0.1:53527        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:49310        127.0.0.1:53527        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:49313        127.0.0.1:64824        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:49349        127.0.0.1:64824        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:49771        127.0.0.1:5354         ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:49772        127.0.0.1:5354         ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:49806        127.0.0.1:62522        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:49985        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:50007        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:50050        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:50053        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:50053        127.0.0.1:62235        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:50054        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:53527        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:53527        127.0.0.1:49309        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:53527        127.0.0.1:49310        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:53527        127.0.0.1:61159        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:53527        127.0.0.1:61160        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:61159        127.0.0.1:53527        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:61160        127.0.0.1:53527        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:61162        127.0.0.1:64824        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:61309        127.0.0.1:50001        TIME_WAIT
  TCP         127.0.0.1:62235        127.0.0.1:50053        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:62522        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:62522        127.0.0.1:49806        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:64823        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:64824        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         127.0.0.1:64824        127.0.0.1:49313        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:64824        127.0.0.1:49349        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         127.0.0.1:64824        127.0.0.1:61162        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:139        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP         192.168.1.5:52125      13.112.39.59:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:52366      3.216.58.47:443        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:58122      52.219.68.189:443      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:60282      13.94.40.40:443        ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:60678      162.159.130.234:443    ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:60894      52.149.21.60:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61248      151.101.129.69:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61250      104.118.66.103:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61257      104.16.24.34:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61282      23.46.129.120:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61285      198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61294      198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61307      192.168.1.1:51234      TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61308      202.218.175.136:80     TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61310      54.236.127.150:443     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61311      202.218.175.136:80     TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61317      192.168.1.1:51236      TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61319      202.218.175.136:80     TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61320      202.218.175.136:80     TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61321      192.168.1.1:51235      TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61322      13.76.217.211:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61324      192.168.1.1:51234      TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61325      202.218.175.136:80     TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61326      202.218.175.136:80     TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61329      13.107.18.254:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61332      204.79.197.222:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61333      192.168.1.1:51235      TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61334      192.168.1.1:51234      TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61340      202.218.175.136:80     TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:61342      192.168.1.1:51235      TIME_WAIT
  TCP         192.168.1.5:62228      40.119.211.203:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:62239      52.149.21.60:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:62253      52.204.144.45:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:62954      40.119.211.203:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP         192.168.1.5:65394      122.215.212.9:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:1947              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:5357              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:7680              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:49664             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:49665             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:49666             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:49667             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:49675             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:49694             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::]:63939             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::1]:49346            [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [::1]:61185            [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:64f5:d8cb:8fd2:2ded]:54015  [2404:6800:4004:808::200d]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:64f5:d8cb:8fd2:2ded]:62233  [2404:6800:4004:81d::200a]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:64f5:d8cb:8fd2:2ded]:62236  [2404:6800:4008:c07::bc]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:64f5:d8cb:8fd2:2ded]:64036  [2404:6800:4004:80e::200d]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a435:a897:2909:6064]:49790  [2404:6800:4004:81c::200a]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:52365  [2600:140b:a000:196::57]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:53107  [2404:6800:4004:81d::200a]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:53113  [2404:6800:4004:81d::200a]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:53422  [2607:5300:60:1567:a585:cd28:2747:ec5a]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:57609  [2404:6800:4004:80a::200a]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:57610  [2404:6800:4004:800::200d]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:60927  [2606:4700::6812:e48]:443  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61249  [2a04:fa87:fffe::c000:4902]:443  TIME_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61252  [2620:116:800e:21:b25f:f2c2:3600:d81a]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61253  [2404:6800:4004:81c::2001]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61259  [2404:6800:4004:81d::2001]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61295  [2404:6800:4004:809::2001]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61312  [2404:6800:4004:819::200d]:443  TIME_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61313  [2404:6800:4004:81f::200e]:443  TIME_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61314  [2404:6800:4004:81f::200e]:443  TIME_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61315  [2404:6800:4004:81f::200e]:443  TIME_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61323  [2606:2800:147:ff8:129b:22eb:20b:1347]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61327  [2620:1ec:c11::200]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61328  [2603:1046:c0a:1835::2]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61330  [2620:1ec:bdf::254]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61331  [2620:1ec:bdf::10]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61336  [2404:6800:4004:807::200a]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61337  [2404:6800:4004:80e::200d]:443  ESTABLISHED
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61338  [2404:6800:4004:81f::200a]:443  TIME_WAIT
  TCP         [2400:4050:a561:d900:a803:f22c:5ac1:83fd]:61339  [2404:6800:4004:807::200a]:443  ESTABLISHED
  UDP         0.0.0.0:500            *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:1947           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:4500           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:5050           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:6666           *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:50728          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:52940          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:52941          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:52943          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:57617          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:61684          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:62000          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:63546          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:63555          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:63557          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:63558          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:63559          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:63560          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:63561          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:63562          *:*
  UDP         0.0.0.0:64187          *:*
  UDP         127.0.0.1:1900         *:*
  UDP         127.0.0.1:55016        *:*
  UDP         127.0.0.1:56827        *:*
  UDP         127.0.0.1:56828        *:*
  UDP         127.0.0.1:63554        *:*
  UDP         192.168.1.5:137        *:*
  UDP         192.168.1.5:138        *:*
  UDP         192.168.1.5:1900       *:*
  UDP         192.168.1.5:5353       *:*
  UDP         192.168.1.5:5353       *:*
  UDP         192.168.1.5:55015      *:*
  UDP         [::]:500               *:*
  UDP         [::]:1947              *:*
  UDP         [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP         [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP         [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP         [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP         [::]:4500              *:*
  UDP         [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP         [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP         [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP         [::]:5355              *:*
  UDP         [::]:50728             *:*
  UDP         [::]:52942             *:*
  UDP         [::]:57617             *:*
  UDP         [::]:62001             *:*
  UDP         [::]:63547             *:*
  UDP         [::]:63556             *:*
  UDP         [::]:64187             *:*
  UDP         [::1]:1900             *:*
  UDP         [::1]:5353             *:*
  UDP         [::1]:5353             *:*
  UDP         [::1]:55014            *:*
  UDP         [fe80::69d5:b3e3:615f:bd3d%12]:1900  *:*
  UDP         [fe80::69d5:b3e3:615f:bd3d%12]:55013  *:*
```

Comment: その「特定のソフトウェア」とやらが192.168.1.5にいないのでは。コマンドプロンプトでnetstat -anを実行してその結果を質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: 192.168.1.5というIPアドレスは127.0.0.1、つまりクライアント側のコードを実行してるのと同じマシンのIPアドレスです。同一マシン内での通信でサーバー側のPython単体では受け取れるのにそのソフト(具体的にはMayaというソフト)で受け取れないのです。そして、そのソフトの127.0.0.1に対して送信すると受け取れるという奇妙な状況です。

Comment: サーバー側(tcpServer.py)で、bindの第１引数が、''になっているのが気になります。
s.bind((192.168.1.5'', 49985))　に変更したら、どうなりますか？

Comment: Fumu 7さん、ありがとうございます！！それでした！そのように変更したら動作しました！

Comment: 192.168.1.5と127.0.0.1が同じマシンだとしても、ソフトウェアがそのIPアドレスに紐付いているかは別の話です。それを確認するためにnetstatの結果が必要です。

Comment: netstat -anの結果を追記しました。s.bind((192.168.1.5'', 49985)のようにすると192.168.1.5に対する接続は許可できました。しかし、もっと汎用的に192.168.1.5以外のIPアドレスに対しても他マシンからアクセスを待ち受ける方法はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> TCP         127.0.0.1:49985        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
> ```

はありますが、192.168.1.5:49985がありません。「特定のソフトウェア」は127.0.0.1でしか待ち受けていないので、接続するクライアントも127.0.0.1に対して接続する必要があります。

bind時に特定のIPアドレスを指定しない場合は、netstatでは

> ```
> TCP         0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
> ```

このように0.0.0.0:nnnで表示されます。このようなポートに対しては、127.0.0.1でも192.168.1.5のようなインターフェースに割り当たっているアドレスでも接続できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！IPアドレスに0.0.0.0を指定したら無事受け取れました！