# 自分自身のIPへのrequestsでWinError 10061が発生する

Tags: python, python-requests

以下のページと同等のことを行おうと考えています。

[Windows/Macに入れたVOICEVOXをPython経由で使う方法](https://ponkichi.blog/voicevox-python-curl)

まずは動作確認のため、ラズパイではなくWindows PC上で行っています。

localhostにrequestsを送ると正常に返ってくるのですが、post先のアドレスを自分のIPアドレスに置き換えるとエラーが出るようになりました。

動かない条件としては、どのようなものがございますでしょうか？

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
[WinError 10061] 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。
```

**正常に動作する例:**

```
r = requests.get("http://localhost:50021/speakers",timeout=(3.0, 10.0))
```

**エラーが出る例:**

```
r = requests.get("http://192.168.50.181:50021/speakers",timeout=(3.0, 10.0))
```

Comment: ブラウザで同じことをしたらどうなりますか？

Comment: netstat -anで192.168.50.181:50021の情報はありますか？

Comment: `netstat -an | find ":50021"` の結果を書いてもらうとわかりやすいかな。Pythonやrequestsは関係なくて、質問文では触れられていない、接続を待ち受けているプログラム側がlocalhostでしか受け付けていない可能性があります。接続を待ち受けているプログラムの設定についても質問文に含めてください。

Comment: この辺の記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[Difference between localhost and the ip address](https://superuser.com/q/196893), [localhost vs real ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6938039/9014308), [サービスにおけるlocalhostとIPアドレスの指定の違い](https://migratory-worker.com/archives/3854)

Comment: 参考: [PythonでTCP通信のエラー: \[WinError 10061\] 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。- スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70153)